# Spring persist Object with unique field creates Duplicate exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persist

I have a USER object (first, last, role_id) and ROLE object (role_id, name), role name is a unique field. From form submit, i get User data along with ROLE name. And since all users have ROLE name of 'user', when I persist User object after the 1st user, I get Duplicate Role name exception. I am sure there is a simple fix for my problem, please help.

In User.java:

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Role
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
private Role role;
```

Save User object:

```
em.persist(aaUser);
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494288/how-to-cascade-persist-only-new-entities

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using `cascade=PERSIST` on the association. That tells JPA that if you `persist` a `User`, then it must also `persist` the associated `Role`. That will work for the first user, but subsequent `User` `persist` operations will fail since the `Role` already exists.

A workaround is to remove the cascade, and you persist the `Role` entity once, before you persist any of the users.

Comment: Thx! So do i have to select role_id by name from ROLE to check if the role name is in already for all the users? and add role_id to User manually before persist the user?